# Javascript get Text from an External Webpage

Tags: javascript

I have looked for a long time but I haven't been able to find a simple solution. On my webpage I want to input an address which will be looked up by a website which returns a webpage where in the text the username I need is located.

https://id.ripple.com/v1/user/  +   the username inputed. It would open the page like https://id.ripple.com/v1/user/rUkUchFYfvjucGtGDtSV2avQCzmJrktkVw where there will be a username parameter containing sashadkiselev. I want to be able to make a function which takes the address opens that webpage retrieves the username and shows it in a pop up box.

Comment: this is done with server side scripting, redirecting.

Comment: you use ajax to fetch that url. read up on ajax, this is a very basic question.

Comment: So you already have the username and then you want to query a URL for the username? ... Why?

Comment: answerers: be aware that https://id.ripple.com/v1/user/sashadkiselev works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As redundant as your request seems, if you are using jQuery, you can have the following code to do what you want:

```
$(function () {
    function getUsername(username, callback) {
        $.getJSON('https://id.ripple.com/v1/user/' + username, function (data) {
            callback.call(data, data.username);
        });
    }

    getUsername('sashadkiselev', function (username) {
        alert('Username is: ' + username);
        // the rest of the data is also available as "this"
    });
});
```

Note that the ability to pass a function as the `callback` parameter to `getUsername()` allows you to easily customise what you do with the username.

Comment: Note that my function current doesn't do any error handling if an error is returned from the URL.